# Why I got NULL instead the related "paises"?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I've `FabricanteDistribuidor.php` entity with this code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor", schema="nomencladores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\FabricanteDistribuidorRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nombre"}, message="El nombre ya está registrado")
 */
class FabricanteDistribuidor
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;

    // ... some other fields

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\Pais")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_distribuidor_pais", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $paises;

    /**
     * Set paises
     *
     * @param  \AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function setPaises(\AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais)
    {
        $this->paises[] = $pais;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paises
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaises()
    {
        return $this->paises;
    }

}
```

Then in the controller I'm trying to get one records and it associated like in this case will be all the `paises` as follow:

```
public function obtenerDetallesFabricanteAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FabricanteDistribuidor')->find($request->query->get('id'));

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response['entities'] = array();

        $dataResponse = array();
        // ... some other fields

        $dataResponse['paises'] = $entity->getPaises();

        $response['entities'][] = $dataResponse;

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
}
```

In the JSON response I get everything fine but `paises` is set to `NULL` and the relation table `fabricante_distribuidor_pais` has value for the `fabricante` I'm seek, why? What I'm doing wrong in the ManyToMany relationship?

I watch in `dev.log` and join is never made:

> doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.direccion AS direccion1, t0.telefono AS
>   telefono2, t0.fax AS fax3, t0.correo AS correo4, t0.id AS id5,
>   t0.nombre AS nombre6 FROM nomencladores.fabricante_distribuidor t0
>   WHERE t0.id = ? ["1"] []

Why?

**Solution and some concerns around it**

After read and read and do a intensive research through Stackoverflow, Google and so on I get the solution, it working, I do not know if is the best of if it's right so you tell me:

**FabricanteDistribuidor.php**

```
class FabricanteDistribuidor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pais", mappedBy="fabricanteDistribuidor", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $paises;


    /**
     * Set paises
     *
     * @param  \AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function setPaises(\Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais)
    {
        $this->paises[] = $pais;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paises
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPaises()
    {
        return $this->paises;
    }

}
```

**Pais.php**

```
class Pais
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor", inversedBy="paises", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_distribuidor_pais", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $fabricanteDistribuidor;

    /**
     * Add fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function addfabricanteDistribuidor(\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor $fabricanteDistribuidor)
    {
        $this->fabricanteDistribuidor[] = $fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }

    /**
     * Get fabricanteDistribuidor
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getfabricanteDistribuidor()
    {
        return $this->fabricanteDistribuidor;
    }

}
```

Then in my controller I iterate over the request looking for each pais I want to add and flush it when the object is persisted:

```
if ($fabricanteDistribuidorForm->isValid()) {
    try {
        $em->persist($fabricanteDistribuidorEntity);
        $em->flush();

        $formDataPais = $request->get('fabricanteDistribuidor')['pais'];
        foreach ($formDataPais as $paisId) {
            $pais = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pais')->find($paisId);
            $fabricanteDistribuidorEntity->setPaises($pais);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $response['entities'][] = $dataResponse;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response['success'] = FALSE;
        $response['error'] = $ex->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    return $this->getFormErrors($fabricanteDistribuidorForm); ;
}
```

That way all works fine and data is persisted in the right way. Now around this solution I have another issue and a concern. The issue is that I'm trying to get now the related `paises` from `FabricanteDistribuidor`as follow and I'm doing something wrong since I can't get their names, so what is wrong in my code?

```
public function obtenerDetallesFabricanteAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FabricanteDistribuidor')->find($request->query->get('id'));

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response['entities'] = array();

        $dataResponse = array();
        // rest of columns  .... 

        if ($entity->getPaises() instanceof Pais) {
            $paises = array();
            foreach ($entity->getPaises() as $pais) {
                $paises[] = $pais->getNombre();
            }

            $dataResponse['paises'] = $paises;
        }

        $response['entities'][] = $dataResponse;
        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
}
```

The concern is around the `Pais` class as you notice I added the inversed side `$fabricanteDistribuidor` so, do I have to insert this any time I want to insert a new `Pais` or is just to tell Doctrine how to deal with proxies inside it? I've not clear yet how owning/inversed side works yet maybe due to this I did thing as my code shown. Any advice around this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my n-m realtions are like this:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sencamer\AppBundle\Entity\Pais")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_distribuidor_pais", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
```

check if in your join sentence, the "fabricante_distribuidor" is a "id".
And remember, you need to put in your constructor to set the "paises" like arrayCollection:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->paises = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

and in the n-m relationship is a good practice create addPaises and not setPaises:

```
public function addPais(\AppBundle\Entity\Pais $pais){
    $this->paises[] = $pais;
    return $this;
}
```

I think, somewhere in your code you add the "paises" to your "fabricante.distribuidor", isn't it?

I hope that helps you

Comment: Hi @roger-guasch finally and after read a lot and keep looking I found a solution just before see yours and I edited my post adding it, can you take a look to it and although the question is not related can you give me some help with the question added to the post in the edit?

Comment: in your try/catch when you use the "$fabricanteDistribuidorEntity->setPaises($pais);" (should be a "add" function and not a "set" function), before the **flush** you should do the **persist**. If you have the relationshops correctly, you can do (without any SQL) the **$fabricanteDistribuidorEntity->getPais()** and get all "paises" of this entity, and the inversed, pais->getFabricateDistribuidor()